# Changing character in a for loop in bash script to execute a program many times

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am new to bash scripting and would like to call a program 22 times. for 22 different files.

file names look something like this:  filename_chr1_test filename_chr2_test filename_chr3_test ... filename_chr22_test

this is my for loop so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for chr_num in {1:22}:
    do
       /path/to/plink --file filename_chr$chr_num_test --exampletest
    done
```

For some reason I'm getting an error back.  I'm not exactly sure why.  Can someone help me debug?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you have to post a clear question.

Comment: 1: for chr_num in {1..22}

2: Use ${chr_num} instead of $chr_num so that the interpreter will work correctly..

Comment: @BradBales Hi brad. OH!  Do I include ( ) around chr_num in the for loop statement AND in where I list the file name?

Comment: Oh, and it's "#!/bin/bash"

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash

for chr_num in {1..22}; do
  /path/to/plink --file filename_chr${chr_num}_test --exampletest
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use brace expansion; use a C-style `for` loop:

```
for((i=1;i<=22;i++)); do
  /path/to/plink --file filename_chr${chr_num}_test --exampletest
done
```

This doesn't require the entire sequence to be expanded in memory at once (not a big deal for a short sequence).

Comment: I suggest to replace three `i` by `chr_num` or one `chr_num` by `i`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner - what is the motivation to use a C-style loop over brace expansion?

Comment: @Sheila The main benefit is that you don't have to hard code the number. You can do `n=42; for ((i=1; i<=n; i++))` but you can't do `for i in {1..n}` . It's also more efficient once you start counting to thousands or millions